# error convert data type

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

i am getting id from the url and pass it to sqldatasource - selectcommand i get the following error :

```
Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '<%=MyIdVal%>'
 to data type int.
```

code behind :

```
Public Partial Class Edit
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles    Me.Load
    MyIdVal = Request.QueryString("id")
End Sub

Private _myIdVal As Integer

Public Property MyIdVal() As Integer
    Get
        Return _myIdVal
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Integer)
        _myIdVal = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

client :

```
 < head runat="server">
<title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
<%=MyIdVal%>
</div>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="myIdDataSource">
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="myIdDataSource" 
    ConnectionString="<%$  ConnectionStrings:myCipConnection  %>" 
    ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myCipConnection.ProviderName %>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = '<%=MyIdVal%>'" >  

    </asp:SqlDataSource>

</form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

the code runs fine when i hardcode it 
any idea how to fix this error thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use `<%= %>` syntax in the select command.  You have to use a parameter in the query, and add a parameter to the SelectParameters collection of the datasource like:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="myIdDataSource" 
  ConnectionString="<%$  ConnectionStrings:myCipConnection  %>" 
  ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myCipConnection.ProviderName %>"
  SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = @id">
     <SelectParameters>
         <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="id" Type="Int32" DefaultValue="1" />
     </SelectParameter>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: if you tell me how to set it i really appreciated

Comment: +1: Oh Brian, I did not see the edit made whgich made my answer a copy cat :)

Comment: @MinaGabriel correction, you do no tneed to programmably set it; it brings in the querystring value for you automatically.